# How do you resize a label by dragging freely in Design mode of a Web form in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I want to drag a side or corner of the label, but it won't let me.  I searched Google & here, but have not found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to Tools -> Options -> HTML Designer -> CSS Styling -> Change positioning to absolute for controls added using Toolbox, paste or drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

Set the width and height:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label" Width="50px" Height="100px"> </asp:Label>
```

Better yet set the css class and do it in a style sheet:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label" CssClass="label"> </asp:Label>
```

In your site.css file:

```
.label {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have said that I wanted to resize it freely in Design mode.  I edited my question.